# Capturing two groups out of a string with a regex

Tags: regex, actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4

I don't know anything about regular expressions and I don't really have the time to study them at the moment.

I have a string like this:

`test (22/22/22)`

I need to capture the `test` and the date `22/22/22` in an array.

the test string could also be a multiple words string:

`test test(1) tes-t (22/22/22)`

should capture `test test(1) tes-t` and `22/22/22`

I have no idea how to get started on this. I managed to capture the date string with the parentheses by doing:

`(\(.*)`

but that really doesn't get me anywhere.

Could someone help me out here and provide an explanation of how I should go about capturing this? I'm kinda lost.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To explain the given regular expression : (.*)\(([^)]+)\)

**(.*)** will match anything, and capture it (the parenthesis capture what their inner expression matches)

**\(** is an escaped parenthesis. That's what you'll write when you wnat to capture a parenthesis.

**[^)]+** means anything but a parenthesis (special characters must not be escaped within square brackets) one or more times.

**([^)]+)** captures what's explained above

**\)** matches a closing parenthesis

So this regex will fail and capture the wrong strings if you have, say, a parenthesis in your first words like in :

> test test(1) tes-t (22/22/22)

**I'd recommend to think about what is the information you want to capture, and how do you spearate it from the rest of your string. This done,it will be much more easier to build an effective regular expression.**

Comment: It looks to me like you haven't escaped your parenthesis as per your second comment in the deconstruction of the regex.

Comment: that's because special characters must not be escapd in square brackets.

Comment: But you have special characters (brackets) outside of the square brackets?

Comment: Yes. Brackets mean "anything within us". ^ is the negation operator. So it will mean : anything but a closing parenthesis. And the + means one or more times.

Comment: I'll spell this out then, shouldn't `(.*)(([^)]+))` be `(.*)(\([^)]+\))` as you haven't escaped the brackets.

Comment: Haha no bother it's sometimes difficult to make complete sense in the comments and I'm not a fan of editing peoples code samples.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
^(.*)\(([^)]*)\)
```

See it here [online on Regexr](http://regexr.com?2vefu)

While hovering with the mouse over the blue colored matches, you can see the content of the capturing groups.

**Explanation**

`^` BeginOfLine

`(.*)` CapturingGroup 1 AnyCharacterExcept\n, zero or more times

`\(([^)]*)\)` ( CapturingGroup 2, AnyCharNotIn[ )] zero or more times

Comment: See my comment to FakeRainBrigand's answer - there should always be an explanation for every solution!

Comment: @weltraumpirat, so back to the PC, added explanation, better now?

Answer (score 0):

This needle works on your example input:

```
(.*)\(([^)]+)\)
```

Comment: You should add an explanation to your solution.  This code will solve OPs problem, but it will not provide any value to other people looking for answers to similar problems - which is an important goal at SO.